# Jenkins with Apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, http-status-code-404

As I wanted to learn `Jenkins`, I am trying to install it. As on the Jenkins site, I've downloaded the war file to run it with `Apache Tomcat`.
I'm able to run Apache tomcat on `localhost:8080` but when I put in `localhost:8080/jenkins` I'm getting a [HTTP Status 404 - /jenkins/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGWk.png).

I've also tried running the war file from the command prompt to open jenkins without tomcat,
by `D:\>java -jar jenkins.war` 
I get these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqja.png) on cmd.

Could you please help, I'm not really sure what's going on.

Thanks for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: Probably you have missed some installation steps, which site did you refer for installation?

Comment: Please check if your war file is not corrupted. Rename the .war to .zip, and try extract / unzip the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply RejeeshChardran,
I've referred the below site.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

Comment: Thanks for the reply W-S, I've done as you suggested, everything seems fine.